Integration Zlib 1.3.1 in Linux environment failing but okay on Windows
I have upgraded my code base to use Zlib 1.3.1 from a very old version. The application works fine on windows but on linux, it's not working as expected. The output of the application is an xlsx file that is compressed using Zlib minizip. While I try to open the Excel, it tells me that the file is corrupted.  Also, I tried to look at the archive generated, and it seems compression has been done based on the Ratio field. The only change in my app that was introduced is an additional param versionMadeBy which I use as 45 and I have been passing NULL to the zip_fileinfo* zipfi while calling zipOpenNewFileInZip4. Anybody else faced similar issue or could suggest how to troubleshoot?When I revert to the previous versions for libminizip.so and for the shared object file calling this lib, then the application works fine and am able to open the Excel with no issues which seems something has gone wrong in the new version integration
Supsect the issue could be at VERSIONMADEBY field but it does work well on Windows

Have you tried unzip -t on the file to check its integrity?
